# Proof related to normal operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.

I look for an elementary proof of the following result:

> If $A,B \in\mathcal{L}(E)$ be two normal operators such that $AB=BA$. Then
>   $$A^*B=BA^*\;\;\text{and}\;\; AB^*=B^*A.$$

If $E$ is finite dimensional, I found a rather difficult proof for this in Proposition 6 in this set of lecture notes ([1](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/makkai/MATH2472010/Notes%20on%20the%20adjoint%20and%20normal%20operators.pdf)).

Comment: Note that in the finite case, if you assume simultaneous diagonalizability then the result follows from properties of the complex numbers (the ones along the diagonals, in particular).

Comment: This is called Fuglede's theorem. The original article is [B. Fuglede: "A commutativity theorem for normal operators", 1950, Theorem 1]. The result there is even a bit more general.

Comment: A very elementary proof using only the operator exponential function and Liouville's theorem can be found in [M. Rosenblum: "On a theorem of Fuglede and Putnam"  (1958)]. I found this information on the [wikipedia page concerning Fuglede's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem) (which is of course quite easy if you already know the theorem's name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof via the multiplication operator representation: the assumption on $A$ and $B$ ($A$ and $B$ bounded normal commuting operators on a Hilbert space $H$) are sufficient for the multiplication operator representation to hold. So up to unitary isomorphism, $A=M_{a}:u\mapsto a(x)u(x)$ and $B=M_{b}:u\mapsto b(x)u(x)$ are multiplication operators on some space $L^2(X,\mu)$, for some bounded Borel measurable functions $a$ and $b$. Then $A^*=M_{\overline a} $ and $B^*=M_{\overline b}$ are multiplication operators too, and they all commute.

Comment: I would not count a proof using the spectral theorem for commuting normal operators as "elementary".

Comment: I agree (besides, some proofs also put $[A^*_i,A_j]=0$ in the hypotheses)

Comment: ... which raises the question, does the proof of the spectral theorem for commuting normal operators use Fuglede's theorem? I have only ever seen it under the additional hypothesis $[A_i^\ast,A_j]=0$.

Comment: One can use, I think, the multiplication operator representation for just one single bounded normal operator $A$, to prove that any other $B$ commuting with $A$ also commutes with $A^*$ (on the lines of the proof for the finite dimensional case).

Answer (score 3):

I find the following proof:

**Lemma:** Let $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. Then, $ST=TS$ if and only if $e^{zS}T=Te^{zS}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

> **Fuglede's Theorem:**  Let $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ with $S$ normal. If $ST=TS$, then $S^*T=TS^*$.

**Proof:** We need to show $e^{zS^*}Te^{-zS^*}=T$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. We have
$$F(z):=e^{zS^*}Te^{-zS^*} = e^{zS^*} e^{-\bar{z} S} T e^{\bar{z} S} e^{-zS^*}=e^{zS^*-\bar{z}S} T e^{-zS^* + \bar{z}S}.$$
Note that $e^{zS^*-\bar{z}S}$ (and its inverse) is unitary (since $zS^*-\bar{z}S$ is anti-self-adjoint), so $\|F(z)\|\leq \|T\|$. Moreover, $F$ is holomorphic
so by Liouville's theorem $F$ is constant. Hence $F(z)=T$ which yields 
$$e^{zS^*}Te^{-zS^*}=T.$$

**Remark:** One can see Lemma 6.1 in this [lecture note](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110660).